# Family tree - cousin relationships with repeated names

Tags: prolog, family-tree

I am trying to get my cousin relationship to work accurately. For example when I do the query: cousins(X,ron).   It returns: X = nancy;X = nancy;X = jeff;X = jeff;X = david;X = thomas.
I believe these are the correct cousins but I don't want to return a name more than once. How can I fix this? And this is the one relationship that is difficult for me to decipher if these are actually cousins or not.

```
parent(A,B) :- mother(A,B); father(A,B).
grandparent(C,E) :- parent(C,D),parent(D,E).
grandmother(C,E) :- mother(C,D),parent(D,E).
grandfather(C,E) :- father(C,D),parent(D,E).
siblings(B,G) :- parent(P,B), parent(P,G), B\=G.
cousins(X,Y) :- parent(A,X), parent(B,Y), siblings(A,B), X\=Y.

mother(mary,sue).
mother(mary,bill).
mother(sue,nancy).
mother(sue,jeff).
mother(jane,ron).
mother(nancy,alice2).
mother(gail,jane).
mother(gail,elaine).
mother(laura,alice).
mother(elaine,david).
mother(sarah,frank).
mother(elaine,thomas).

father(john,sue).
father(john,bill).
father(bob,nancy).
father(bob,jeff).
father(bill,ron).
father(charlie,alice2).
father(david,charlie).
father(carl,jane).
father(peter,laura).
father(frank,thomas).
father(frank,david).
father(thomas,alice).
father(henry,frank).

(ancestor(A,D):-parent(A,D)).
(ancestor(A,D):-(parent(P,D),ancestor(A,P))).
```

Comment: instead of `\=` try `@<`

Comment: no that did not work...it made the siblings relationship invalid

Comment: i'll try that in SWI prolog. Sometimes SWISH does weird things

Comment: so it did not work In SWI prolog either. and my original code is returning every cousin name twice in SWI prolog.

Comment: You should check `siblings/2` behavior first since `cousins/2` depends upon it. `siblings/2` looks like it will succeed twice for anyone who shares two parents. You need to adjust your `siblings/2` logic. Actually, it will succeed 4 times because of the symmetry. Try the query `siblings(X, Y)`.

Comment: yeah siblings(X, bill). returns sue twice because they have the same father and mother

Comment: but that's not what i want obviously. if i query siblings(X, elaine). it only returns Jane because they only have the same mother

Comment: When you have a rule like, `parent(A,B) :- mother(A,B); father(A,B).`, you're going to get possibly two logically distinct solutions to a query like `parent(P, john)` if they have two parents. If you want your rules to be as general as possible (not lose solutions) and not use a cut (`!`) or `once/1`, there's not much you can do about it as there's no further logical reduction to be done or tighter conditions to check. Logically speaking, there are two solutions. In those cases, you can let your predicate find all the solutions then use something like `setof/3` to get a unique collection.